# Why can't I invert my image back to original with CIFilter in my Swift iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

I'm working on a simple app. 
It has an image view with pre-loaded image and a button.
When pressed the button should invert the image in the image view.

It works the first time, but I expect it to invert the image back to its original form when I press the button again.
However it crashes on this second press of the button.

Here is the relevant code from `ViewController.swift`:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var invertButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func invertButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let beginImage = CIImage(image: imageView.image!)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")!
        filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        imageView.image = UIImage(CIImage: (filter.outputImage)!)
    }
```

Basically, `beginImage` becomes `nil` the second time around and I have no idea why. I have tried debugging by splitting those dense lines into as many `let` assignments as I can but something mysteriously happens with that `CIImage` constructor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(CIImage: (filter.outputImage)!)
```

You can't do that. A CIImage does not magically turn into a UIImage. An image view needs a *bitmap*-based image, not a CIImage-based image. You have to *render* the CIImage to turn it into a UIImage, either by getting a CIContext and telling it to create CGImage or by drawing the CIImage into a graphics context.

Comment: And see my example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch02p070filters/ch15p419filters/ViewController.swift Note that there are three cases at the end; you want to use the case 1 technique or the case 2 technique. The case 3 technique doesn't work - and that's the one you are using.