# CIColorControls & UISlider w/ Swift 4

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I am trying to make a slider affect the brightness of a UIImageView.

My outlet and action:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var previewImage: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func adjustBrightness(_ sender: UISlider) {

        let currentValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
        print(currentValue)

        let coreImage = CIImage(image: previewImage.image!)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(currentValue, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)

        if let ciimage = filter!.outputImage {
            let filteredImage = ciimage
            previewImage.image = UIImage(ciImage: filteredImage)
        }
     }
```

and my min/max vals:
[image]

My image is turning pure white and ignoring the slider input/sender.value vals. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: You need a value between -1 and +1.

Comment: Thanks Tamas. I tired the fix on your post didnt seem to work for me. Also tried setting max min to -1 > 1

Comment: It should be from 0 to 1. Zero means no change at all and one means totally white

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875114/why-cant-i-invert-my-image-back-to-original-with-cifilter-in-my-swift-ios-app

Comment: @andehlu you overwrite the image inside the imageView every chnage in slider so it will get the last change every rerun of the action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
previewImage.image = UIImage(ciImage: filteredImage)
```

You cannot magically make a UIImage out of a CIImage by using that initializer. Your image view is coming out empty because you are effectively setting its image to `nil` by doing that. Instead, you must *render* the CIImage. See, for example, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875114/why-cant-i-invert-my-image-back-to-original-with-cifilter-in-my-swift-ios-app).

(Apple claims that the image view itself will render the CIImage in this configuration, but I've never seen that claim verified.)

However, we might go even further and point out that if the goal is to allow the user to move a slider and change the brightness of the image in real time, your approach is never going to work. You cannot use a UIImageView *at all* to display an image that will do that, because every time the slider is moved, we must render again, and that is *really really slow*. Instead, you should be using a Metal view to render into (as described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656483/how-is-filters-uiscrollview-uicollectionview-in-apples-photos-app-implemented-t/51753747#51753747)); that is the way to respond in real time to a CIFilter governed by a slider.

Comment: Yup created a new image view and rendered the filteredImage to it perfectly. Thank you. The output orientation seems to have rotated though 90 CCW. Any ideas on why that may have happened?

Comment: Yes, if you just search on that you'll find it has been well discussed here. You've lost your orientation setting. — Please don't ignore the last paragraph (just added) of my answer above. If you want the user to slide a slider and have the image respond in real time, what you're doing will never work.

Comment: the image returned isn't nil , it's overwritten every drag of slider with last white change

Comment: Ok thanks for your help @matt I can see it acting pretty sluggish. Is this the Metal version in your example? https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch02p070filters/ch15p419filters/ViewController.swift

Sorry just saw your update in your answer.

Comment: No, that's the slow way. The metal view should be the next example if I remember rightly.